# Do humans have free will?

Tags: bible, nature-of-god, nature-of-man, free-will

Something confuses me. God is omniscient, meaning He knows everything, including our decisions in life. God says we have free will, but how is that so if I can't make the choice to *not* do something God knows for a fact that I will do.

If God knows I will do something, I don't have the free will to *not* do it, meaning I don't have free will at all. So why does He say we have free will?

Comment: Also a truth question since it has no scope or perspective from which to answer.

Comment: You could scope a question like this by narrowing it down to an answerable level.  For example 'did Calvin believe humans have free will?' is a answerable question.